# a plugin path issue with gazebo_classic

Tags: gazebo, ros2, plugin

I Solved it. Just apt update and upgrade

I'm having a plugin path issue with gazebo_classic.

The Gazebo log outputs the following:

`(1709002150 963680455) [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin gazebo_ros2_control/lib/libgazebo_ros2_control.so: gazebo_ros2_control/lib/libgazebo_ros2_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When running ros2 launch with the corresponding log, the log outputs the following.

`[gzserver-2] gzserver: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libgazebo_ros2_control.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18hardware_interface15ResourceManager9load_urdfERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEbb`

Search results showed that this problem was related to a plugin.

But I don't know how to approach it.

thank you for reading

Comment: I solved it. Just apt update and upgrade. Thank you